# ssh: Cannot use pubkey authentication

Tags: server, ssh, authentication

I've been unable to ssh using pubkey authentication. I've been setting up a new server, and it just won't work.

My changes to the default sshd_config are set with this:

```
sed -i 's/#PasswordAuthentication.*/PasswordAuthentication no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/#PermitRootLogin.*/PermitRootLogin no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
sed -i 's/X11Forwarding.*/X11Forwarding no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

A run from the server:

```
user@storage:~/.ssh$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:nC8X55Nqg+Tl222a3FtJy304XPzIpEU9LwXxFB5iTa8
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:DpGM4IpHZ4RVwH1AUhnle9Ts51y2vrgLFBtGC+sa1Ho
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:6//2szDkpcZRGEdamM0/kgvH5xYR19/pQmTrjtLSGNU
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-p'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='2222'
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 2222.
debug1: Bind to port 2222 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 2222.
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_8.2, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:nC8X55Nqg+Tl222a3FtJy304XPzIpEU9LwXxFB5iTa8
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:DpGM4IpHZ4RVwH1AUhnle9Ts51y2vrgLFBtGC+sa1Ho
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:6//2szDkpcZRGEdamM0/kgvH5xYR19/pQmTrjtLSGNU
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 192.168.1.10 port 34130 on 192.168.1.13 port 2222 rdomain ""
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 126/65534 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: Sending SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg ssh-ed25519 pkblob ED25519 SHA256:FSrXJhrKh9s4r+GzeZ2NE6Pkwdbp/LNChHNz0OP34jk [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for user from 192.168.1.10 port 34130 ssh2: ED25519 SHA256:FSrXJhrKh9s4r+GzeZ2NE6Pkwdbp/LNChHNz0OP34jk
debug1: userauth-request for user user service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug1: userauth_pubkey: test pkalg ecdsa-sha2-nistp521 pkblob ECDSA SHA256:T62aYA0CM4ZkwiU6GffBRP0j5gP6Jjown8DF/pQsfAE [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: fd 4 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1000/1000 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys2
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/user/.ssh/authorized_keys2': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for user from 192.168.1.10 port 34130 ssh2: ECDSA SHA256:T62aYA0CM4ZkwiU6GffBRP0j5gP6Jjown8DF/pQsfAE
Connection closed by authenticating user user 192.168.1.10 port 34130 [preauth]
debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
debug1: monitor_read_log: child log fd closed
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: Killing privsep child 72241
debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

Relevant permissions on my homedir, .ssh, and authorized_keys:

```
drwxr-xr-x 18 user user 4096 Sep 16 07:31 user/
drwx------  2 user user 4096 Sep 16 07:31 .ssh/
-rw-r--r--  1 user user   96 Sep 16 06:42 authorized_keys
```

As an experiment I set `PasswordAuthentication yes`, and was able to connect. Additionally, I was also able to connect to another server which is using pubkey authentication (w/ the same key) successfully so I know the client has the key setup properly for use.

Comment: Do you actually have that key listed in `authorized_keys`?

Comment: Yes, my authorized keys file reads:
```ssh-ed25519 PUBKEY user@core``` where `PUBKEY` is actually the proper key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I figured it out... adding a blank line to the top of my `authorized_keys` file did the trick

Comment: That's weird, but if it works it works! Congratulations on answering your own question. Please accept your answer as the correct one by clicking on the gray check mark   and turn it green ✅. This will indicate the problem is solved may help others.